# What does parseInt do exactly?

Tags: java, parsing, int

What does parseInt do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

A String cannot be used like an int. With parseInt you can convert a string to an int.

```
public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String value = "1000";
// Parse with parseInt: the string can be negative.
int result = Integer.parseInt(value);
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(result + 1);
```